# Why would my garage remote stop working after replacing the battery?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

My garage remote recently stopped working. I recently replaced the remotes battery, and it did not fix the problem. I ran out of ideas how to troubleshoot this and would appreciate any advice with this.

Comment: First thing to try is re-pairing it with the controller.

Comment: Also the manual for your opener will likely have a troubleshooting section.

Comment: I had this same question and REALLY didn't want to replace my garage remote without knowing for sure that it was faulty, and here is what I figured out: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/228417/20576

Answer (score 1):

Check that you put the battery in the right way.  Then use a multimeter to check its voltage and/or try a different known-good battery.  Then I would follow Steven's advise to reset the code and check the manual.  (You can likely find the manual online.)

Answer (score 0):

Push the red button on the side of the opener.

When you push the button not only does it open the door, but it changes the frequency for the next push. If the transmitter and the receiver get out of sequence, the frequency will be off. The red button resets the cycle.

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: the way the remote works is that when you push the button not only does it open the door, but it changes the frequency for the next push.  If the transmitter and the receiver get out of sequence, the freq will be off.  the red button resets the cycle.  hit the red button and then the remote.

Comment: What red button? Where is this located?